# PHP Execute Code once every 24 hours

Tags: php, sql, timestamp

I am trying to create a PHP code that will execute once every 24 hours. The current CMS that I am using supports this, and it works correctly, whereas, I want to make it a little more complicated.

For one hour, every day, I want a code to execute, which will give special permissions to my users during this one hour.

Once the hour is up, I would like it to revert the changes, taking away the permissions. The users would then need to wait until the next day, when the hour is back.

For example:

```
<?php

if (!defined('UBER') || !UBER)
{
    exit;
}

dbquery("UPDATE catalog_pages SET visible = '1' WHERE id='91'");
$core->Mus('update_catalogue');

?>
```

This code executes once every 24 hours, and works fine. It updates the catalogue setting a page to be visible to everyone. I am only stuck on how to make it disappear after the hour is up.

Lets say that the hour is 4.00am to 5.00am.

How would I make the page disappear after 5.00am using a PHP code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're *much* better off writing a "cron" script (Linux) or a "scheduled task" (Windows).

Comment: The CMS I am currently using uses a cron script. From the database, you can select how so often the script will execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (date("G") == '4'){
//give
}elseif (date("G") == '5'){
//takeway
}
```

or in the query

```
.. WHERE HOUR(NOW()) BETWEEN 4 AND 5
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Pretty simple, although, is there a way to choose the times using a timestamp instead? I'm fairly new at PHP.

Comment: I should mention, from my database, you need to set how so often the code will execute. I have it set to every 24 hours at the moment.
I also want to be able to make the "hour" change. For example: one day at 4am, the next day at 6am.

Comment: Yes, the SQL version is what I was looking for. But instead of having between 4 and 5, could you some how make a "rotation", as I mentioned, one day 4am, the next day at 6am?

Comment: you would have to store yesterdays value somewhere and just increment start and finish times (up to 24)

Comment: Would you be able to give an example? Sorry, I see what you are talking about, but I am having trouble "picturing" how it would work out.
In my database, it currently stores the last time that the script executed, but I am not sure how you would increase that time by 1 hour for example.
In the cron file, would I make it add 1 hour on to the last execution time for it to successfully work?

Comment: add a db field for the hour, extract it; 4 becomes the hour+1 and 5 the hour +2

Comment: can this also be done using a timestamp?
3600000 = 1 hour

7200000 = 2 hours?
Because the time in the database is currently in timestamp form.

Comment: yes, should be fine, how every your currently recording the hour.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually really easy to do.  When the user logs on or tries to use a permission that is only granted at the certain time, run a check to see if the time is within those hours.  If your CMS allows you to intercept events, use something like this:

```
onUserAction(){
    if(isSpecialHour()){
        denyPermission()...
    }
    else{
        grantPermission()...
    }
}
```

When the user tries to do something that requires a permission, the system should check if it is within that special hour period and then either grant or deny permission.

With PHP alone, it is impossible to have a script run at a specific interval.  PHP scripts are run when they are loaded, and unless you have someone run the scrip at that exact time (or use something like cron) it can not be done.  Of course, you could use cron or simmilar to accomplish the same thing.  The above method is probably your best bet though.

Comment: If you need the "special privileges" hour to be changeable, simply store the start time (timestamp) in your database and have the isSpecialHour() function see if it is within the allowed hour.  You can have isSpecialHour() check where ever you want, so you can change the hour that the permissions are given at your own will.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. But with the changeable hour, I want it to be automatic so that every time zone has their fair "chance" of being able to use the special permission.

Comment: again thats no problem.  simply have the isSpecialHour() function check the timezone for the user that is trying to access the permission